# How does the command pattern solve the problem of hard-wired commands/requests?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, game-development

I'm reading *Game Programming Patterns* by Robert Nystrom and have a question about the command pattern.

In the first example of the [Configuring Input](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html#configuring-input) section, an if/else statement hard-codes game actions to console buttons:

```
void InputHandler::handleInput()
{
  if (isPressed(BUTTON_X)) jump();
  else if (isPressed(BUTTON_Y)) fireGun();
  else if (isPressed(BUTTON_A)) swapWeapon();
  else if (isPressed(BUTTON_B)) lurchIneffectively();
}
```

Since the key mappings are hard-coded at compile-time, the user cannot change/configure them according to their preferences at run-time. The command pattern is then introduced as a solution to this problem:

```
// ***Command interface***
class Command
{
public:
  virtual ~Command() {}
  virtual void execute() = 0;
};

// ***Concrete commands***
class JumpCommand : public Command
{
public:
  virtual void execute() { jump(); }
};

class FireCommand : public Command
{
public:
  virtual void execute() { fireGun(); }
};

[...]


// ***Input handler***
class InputHandler
{
public:
  void handleInput();

  // Methods to bind commands...

private:
  Command* buttonX_;
  Command* buttonY_;
  Command* buttonA_;
  Command* buttonB_;
};

void InputHandler::handleInput()
{
  if (isPressed(BUTTON_X)) buttonX_->execute();
  else if (isPressed(BUTTON_Y)) buttonY_->execute();
  else if (isPressed(BUTTON_A)) buttonA_->execute();
  else if (isPressed(BUTTON_B)) buttonB_->execute();
}
```

**Questions**

It's not clear to me how the command pattern helps to make the input mappings run-time configurable. There must be some table in the GUI that allows the user to specify a key for each action type: <commandName, key>, but how do we create these key bindings at runtime?

I think we would need to use the `new` keyword to initialise the pointers, e.g. `buttonX_ = new JumpCommand;`, but I'm not sure exactly how to create the bindings and I don't understand why this cannot be done with an if/else at run-time.

I have some experience with JS and none with C++, so would be grateful if someone who is familiar with both languages could help me flesh out/understand what's going on in this example.

Comment: As you say, you will need to set up the bindings by initializing the pointers, so you might have a default set of bindings where you assign button x to jump and so on. Then you might have a way for the user to configure the bindings, e.g they could choose to have left handed settings so you just reassign the pointers to new commands. Having commands can also help if you have different interfaces, eg with a keyboard you might jump on spacebar etc.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I mostly come across examples of the command pattern in those two languages and since design patterns are not language specific, I figured maybe someone who has used the command pattern in Java to solve this problem would be able  to shed some light. I didn't mean to violate community guidelines though and have removed the tag.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Ian4264, yes, I'd like to see how that reassignment is done. Currently, I'm imagining we have some sort of key settings table in the GUI where the first column of each row is a command name, e.g. "Jump" and the second column is some sort of input that allows the user to specify the key they would like to use to invoke that command, e.g. spacebar. But why do we need the command pattern to make these bindings at runtime? Wouldn't it suffice to convert this table into a map/dictionary of the format <commandName, key> and then use a simple if/else to do if(isPressed(keymap["jump"])) jump()? –

Answer (score 0):

#### Implementation

I've changed the code a bit so it's simpler. So, here are the commands:

```
using Command = void (*)();
void jump(); // TODO
void fire(); // TODO
```

and buttons:

```
enum class Button { x, y, a, b };
bool pressed(Button); // TODO
```

Here's how a [customizable key -> `Command`] mapping can be stored and used for handling input. It differs a bit from the one you presented: I `static_cast` `Button` <-> `std::size_t` to use `Button`s as "keys"; `Command`s are "values":

```
class Buttons {
    std::array<Command, 4> commands{jump, jump, fire, fire};
public:
    void rebind(Button button, Command command) {
        commands[static_cast<std::size_t>(button)] = command;
    }
    void handle() {
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < commands.size(); ++i)
            if (pressed(static_cast<Button>(i)))
                commands[i]();
    }
};
```

So, if it turns out the user wants to e.g. use `x` to jump, `rebind(Button::x, jump)` should be called. The original solution doesn't provide unified rebinding because each `Command` is a separate field, so I used an array instead.

#### Why?

> But why do we need the command pattern to make these bindings at runtime?

We don't, it's just an option, a common approach.

> Wouldn't it suffice to convert this table into a map/dictionary of the format <commandName, key> and then use a simple if/else to do if(isPressed(keymap["jump"])) jump()?

If string names are changed to named integral constants, dictionary - to array, I like your solution even more because it avoids indirect/virtual function calls, which are slower and `template`/overload-incompatible.